# PropTypes for Animated.Value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes, react-animated

I've defined Animated Value at parent as below

```js
const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);

console.log(scrollY); // 0;
console.log(typeof scrollY); // object;
```

Then I need to pass this value to my component as below

```js
<ChildComponent animatedValue={scrollY} />
```

Now I'm wondering, at `ChildComponent`, what should be the correct proptype for my props `animatedValue`?

```js
ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  animatedValue: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

If I define as `PropTypes.number` I get warning which make sense because typeof `scrollY` is object.

But we can't define below due to eslint error, for object we should be using PropTypes.shape,
but I have no idea what shape should I set?

```js
ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  animatedValue: PropTypes.object.isRequired // eslint error
};
```

Comment: I usually just use PropTypes.object and ignore the eslint error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check that the passed object is an instance of a class

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(Animated.Value)
```